# PHP 5.4 problems using &amp in http query

Tags: php

I'm having some problems when I perform an xml reading procedure from an external page.

When I run by shell
`php get.php`
the return is what I expect.

but when I run via browser
the return is :

> PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity
>   "http://------------/search.php?q=CITY&format=xml&quot; in
>   /var/www/html/get.php on line 5

how do I disable use of &amp when the query is via browser?

FILE get.php content:

```
<?php
ini_set('arg_separator.input', '&'); 
ini_set('arg_separator.output', '&'); 
$request_url = "--------/search.php?q=CITY&format=xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
print_r($array);exit;  
?>
```

Comment: that is not about ampersand that is about not existing domain call `http://------------/`! what domain do you expect to reach?

Comment: To me the "it works in the CLI but not in the browser" would suggest that your CLI and FPM/FastCGI configurations differ somehow. Check the output of `php -i` (cli) and `phpinfo()` ("browser") for which ini file it's loading, and if they are different, that could be the culprit.

Comment: Why are you doing anything with the `arg_separator` directives? The `&amp;` red herring? And not sure error message goes exactly with code as shared.

Comment: You know PHP version 5.4 is unsafe and should be upgraded, see http://php.net/supported-versions.php